# Why does my volumetric atmosphere not have an orange sunset region?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, procedural, volumetrics

So this is the effect I'm looking for:

[image]

This orange glow in an atmosphere, right where the shadowy and the light side meet. However, my material (which should be pretty physically accurate as far as I can tell) doesn't have it:

[image]

If I really up the density of my atmosphere, I can get a sunset effect, when viewing from some specific viewpoints:

[image]

However, looking at the planet straight on, there still isn't any hint of orange, not to mention that the density completely ruins the other areas on the planet:

[image]

The material I used for the atmosphere is this:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas why the orange glow isn't there?